# Highcharts, display marker on selected point only

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I would like to display spline graph without marker on the line. This is done.
But now, When a point is selected, the marker doesn't appear.

I found a little hack to do what I want. In plotOptions, radius is set to 0.1 to be hidden by the line width.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
            marker: {
                radius: 0.1, // hack to show selected point
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        radius: 5
                    },
                    select: {
                        radius: 5
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Complete code is here : http://jsfiddle.net/ManUtopiK/7GXeT/

**This is an HighCharts bug or I made a mistake in graph options ?**

Comment: This is most likely a Highchart issue, may be by design. If you have `markers.enabled=false`, `markers.states.hover.enabled=true` & `markers.states.select.enabled=true` the selection behavior doesn't work as expected, but if you just change to `markers.states.hover.enabled=false` and leave other two as is, the selection behavior now works as expected. Try @ http://jsfiddle.net/7GXeT/3/

Comment: @JugalThakkar No, when a selected point is hovered, the mark disappear.

Comment: @ManUtopiK yes correct, like I said, looks like a bug on highchart's end

Comment: I'm having this issue as well, it seems to be a Highcharts bug. Thanks for the radius hack!

Answer (score -2):

If you set your marker to have enabled: false you still show the marker point if you hover over the point (when the tooltip popup appers).
See updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/7GXeT/2/):

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        marker: {
            enabled: false,
            //radius: 0.1, // hack to show selected point
            states: {
                hover: {
                    radius: 5
                },
                select: {
                    radius: 5
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I tried, it doesn't work. Marker for hover is displayed, but not marker for selected point. I want a marker when I click on a point on the line !

Comment: Trying to select a point on the chart in your fiddle makes the point invisible. I have reported this to the Highcharts creator(s), and have had it confirmed that this is indeed the current, however incorrect, behavior of the markers. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2811#issuecomment-37530016) for their response.